# How can I input part of a file in verbatim?

Tags: verbatim, input, code

I'm writing the documentation to a large piece of Matlab code. I would like include tags in my Matlab code and then read the lines of code between the tags into Latex and output them as verbatim (or use some other form of code representation such as the lstlisting package).

I noticed that the [catchfile](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/catchfile.html) package can help me with reading code as verbatim (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14145/how-do-i-create-a-macro-which-reads-the-content-of-a-file-when-the-macro-is-defin)) and that the [catchfilebetweentags](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/) package does essentially the other part of the job (as described in the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file), yet I'm still struggling to do both simultaneously. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered the other way round? Creating a LaTeX document and extracting the Matlab code? This is called literate programming and there are several systems to support it.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file if you haven't already.

Comment: You can use tags with listings see documentation `5.7 Arbitrary linerange markers`

Comment: Perfect, the arbitrary linerange markers were exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to use `catchfilebetweentags`.  I would write a script to extract each code section into its own file, then use the [`mcode` package](http://www.advancedmcode.org/integrating-latex-with-matlabm-code-latex-package.html) to include the file in the doc.

You might find `mcode` useful anyway, since it does the matlab syntax highlighting for you.

```
\lstinputlisting{/SOME/PATH/FILENAME.M}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=6, lastline=15]{/SOME/PATH/FILENAME.M}
```

Comment: Yes, it's this plus the arbitrary line-range markers.

Comment: You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.