# Environment that applies sizeN.clo

Tags: macros, environments, fontsize

My document has a base font size of 12pt, but I want the figures to be typeset as if the base font size were 10pt (some of the figures use graphics packages that hardwire font size commands rather than offering `\foosize` indirections, so I can't just fix it that way).

I have found [Switching to different font size(s) locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/switching-to-different-font-sizes-locally), so my goal is to wrap that up in a `\newenvironment`.  **EDIT:** It is not quite as simple as using [How do I create a macro which reads the content of a file when the macro is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14145/how-do-i-create-a-macro-which-reads-the-content-of-a-file-when-the-macro-is-defi/14147), but I now have this:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\tenpointdecl}{size10.clo}{\makeatletter}
\newenvironment{fontsizeten}{%
  \let\saveendinput\endinput
  \let\endinput\relax
  \let\savenewcommand\newcommand
  \let\newcommand\renewcommand
  \tenpointdecl
  \let\newcommand\savenewcommand
  \let\endinput\saveendinput
}{}
```

This works, but strikes me as inelegant.  It would be better if there were a way to rewrite the contents of `\tenpointdecl` so that the `\let`s every time it is invoked were unnecessary.  Suggestions?

Comment: Those `\let` are necessary and take up a negligible amount of time.

Comment: I'm not concerned with time, but with tidiness.

Comment: One might think to do a "search and replace" of `\newcommand` with `\renewcommand`, but this is not possible; **etoolbox**'s `\patchcmd` can do only a one shot search and replace at a time and one should know how many `\newcommand` are to be changed. It might be used to cut off the `\endinput`, but it's like using a gun to kill a fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One has to avoid reading `\endinput`, besides redefining `\newcommand`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{catchfile,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\clo@newcommand\newcommand
\let\clo@endinput\endinput
\CatchFileDef{\clo@sizeten}{size10.clo}{}

\newenvironment{fontsizeten}
  {\par                           % go in vertical mode
   \let\endinput\relax            % neutralize \endinput
   \let\newcommand\renewcommand   % the commands are already defined
   \clo@sizeten                   % "read" the file
   \let\endinput\clo@endinput     % revert to the original command
   \let\newcommand\clo@newcommand % revert to the original command
  }
  {\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{fontsizeten}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{fontsizeten}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

As usual, **lipsum** is used only to create dummy text. The original meaning of `\newcommand` and `\endinput` should be restored immediately after the redefinitions of `size10.clo` have been performed.

Comment: As you can see from my edit, I came up with nearly the same thing based on Martin Scharrer's suggestion.  I don't understand why it's necessary to neutralize `\ProvidesFile`, it appears to be harmless?  The "circular definition of `\normalsize`" isn't causing me any trouble either.

Comment: @Zack That's quite strange. I don't know why, but the first approach stopped at `\normalsize`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider rereading the file every time. This wouldn't be that less efficient as long you don't switch quite a lot.

Anyway, you can assign the content of the file to a macro using the [`catchfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) package. It requires e-TeX and avoids the issues you having. 
See also [How do I create a macro which reads the content of a file when the macro is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14145/how-do-i-create-a-macro-which-reads-the-content-of-a-file-when-the-macro-is-defi/14147#14147).

The problems you see is for once that TeX's `\input` (`\@@input` in LaTeX) doesn't work in `\edef` (or the global `\xdef`), because AFAIK TeX considers its an error when it encounters the end of a file during a macro definition. Also you shouldn't use `\edef` or `\xdef` because this expands not only `\@@input`, but also its content. You don't want that! You would need to use `\expandafter` instead, but this doesn't work either because of the above reason.