# Automated plotting with \input inside \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, input, external-files

I'm trying to draw some figures with externally generated data.  I'd like to draw a simple line inside a `tikzpicture` using `pgfplots` like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:10]
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[blue] (x, 5 * x + 7);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I'd like to define the plotted equation in a separate file.  This does not work:

```
\addplot[blue] (x, \input{math.txt});
```

(with `math.txt` containing simply `5 * x + 7`).  Neither does this:

```
\addplot[blue] (x, \protected\input{math.txt});
```

or this:

```
\addplot[blue] \input{math.txt}
```

(with `math.txt` containing `(x, 5 * x + 7);`).

In all cases, I get an error like

```
! Argument of \pgfplotsforeachungrouped@ has an extra }.
```

which isn't particularly instructive to me in this context.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this short of wrapping the whole thing in Perl or something?  Apparently the `input` command isn't quite as low level as I thought.

In case it matters, I'm on a Windows 7 machine running MiKTeX 2.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach from [How do I create a macro which reads the content of a file when the macro is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14145/how-do-i-create-a-macro-which-reads-the-content-of-a-file-when-the-macro-is-defi) to store the file contents in a macro, which can then be used in the `\addplot` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{math.txt}
5 * x + 7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef{\foo}{math.txt}{}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:10]
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[blue] (x, \foo);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```